# How to install Metasploit Community on a remote headless Debian box?

Tags: debian, metasploit

After attempting to get Metasploit to work nice with my desktop box (with limited success), I've decided to instead set it up on on separate box. However, it seems like the Metasploit community installer requires a GUI to install it, which I of course don't have on a server box I'm SSHed into. I do not want access to Metasploit framework only and really want the web UI, how can I still make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This wil install Metasploit Framework, and not Metasploit Community. The commandline version is way more powerfull once you know you way around it. Some instructions can be found [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/).

### The hard way

Darkoperator has an excellent write-up of this at his [blog](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/). Precise commands are at this blog, but I will sketch the idea.

1. Install dependencies for Metasploit Framework
2. Install Ruby
3. Install Nmap (optional)
4. Install & configure PostgreSQL server
5. Install & configure the Metasploit framework

### The somewhat easier way

Install [PTF](https://github.com/trustedsec/ptf). This is a framework that was made to make installing pentesting tools easier. After the install, you can run `./ptf use modules/exploitation/metasploit`. This will install all the dependecies and automagically set Metasploit up.